# Failed prop stype:Invalid prop 'value' of type 'object' supplied to 'TextInput' expected 'string'

Tags: react-native

I don't know why I am getting the warning while assigning value in the value prop of FloatLabel component.
Thanks in advance

```html
<FloatLabel
  inputStyle={styletheme.inputLabel}
  labelStyle={styletheme.labelInput}
  style={styletheme.formInput}
  keyboardType="email-address"
  onChangeText={(email)=>this.onEmailIdChange(email)}
  onBlur={(email)=>this.onEmailIdChange(email)}
  onFocus={(email)=>this.onEmailIdChange(email)}
  value={this.state.email.emailId}
 >
 E-mail id
 </FloatLabel>
 this.state= {
              email:{
                emailId:'',
                emailIdError:false,
                color:'rgba(255,255,255,1)'
               }
             }
```

[image]

Comment: Pass string to the value parameter  -------- value={JSON.stringify(this.state.email.emailId)} ------------

Comment: @Pramod I have tried using the above method but when I insert the values after that they are not being kept in the field they are getting erased

Comment: value={(text) => this.setState({email : text})}

Comment: @Pramod for setting the state I am already using   onChangeText={(email)=>this.onEmailIdChange(email)} and email is an object in state